# How to embed snowflake data visualization in my react page?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I want to display snowflake data in visualization format in my react page. I am able to create a sample data in snowflake and visualize within snowflake but i want to embed this visualization in my react page, how to achieve this? i don't see any connector api to access this display from my react page.

Comment: If you are referring to [Snowsight Dashboards](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-dashboards.html) then there is no connector API for that. You can probably use [Node.js driver](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver.html) to query the data but you would need another JS lib to build visualizations.